# Cannot see logs on JellyBean

Tags: android, logging, android-logcat, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Is there a way to see the logs in Android Jelly bean 4.2 and above.

aLogCat application no longer reads logs from my application. I can see the logs on a 4.1 device but cannot see them on a 4.2.2 device.

I have tried Volume Up + Power Up + Down but no use.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your Android SDK, Android Jelly Bean MR1 devices (4.2) doesn't work with old SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Since Android 4.1, unless your device is rooted, apps can only access their own log entries. Third party applications can no longer get the read logs permission. If you want to capture logs for your application, you will need to do that within your app yourself. ACRA is an excellent library for doing just that.